# How to re run only failed test cases in cypress and azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress, testcase, mochawesome

I've running testcases in azure pipeline but for some reason testcases fail randomly, I just want it to re run only the failed ones, not the whole suite, same as well in local

I've tried retires option but it runs the whole suite, whichever passed those are also running again

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to re-run only the failed tests in Azure Pipelines.

We can re-run the failed jobs which contain any failed steps (such as the failed test step). Re-running the failed jobs would re-run all the steps within the jobs.